# https://onesignal.com/api/v1//notifications: http.DefaultTransport and http.DefaultClient are not available in App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, go, onesignal

When i tried to implement push notification in golang App Engine using onesignal enviorment.But iam getting error "http.DefaultTransport and http.DefaultClient are not available in App Engine".This is my code,

```
func (c *PushNotificationController) CreateNotification() {
    client := onesignal.NewClient(nil)
    client.AppKey = "MyAppKey"
    client.UserKey = "MyUserKey"
    notifID := CreateNotifications(client)
    log.Println(notifID)
}

func CreateNotifications(client *onesignal.Client) string {
    playerID := "SamplePlayerId" // valid
    notificationReq := &onesignal.NotificationRequest{
        AppID:            "MyAppKey",
        Contents:         map[string]string{"en": "English message"},
        IsIOS:            true,
        IncludePlayerIDs: []string{playerID},
    }
    if createRes, res, err := client.Notifications.Create(notificationReq){
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        return createRes.ID
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use http on appengine, you have to use urlfetch.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/urlfetch/reference

i.e. the package you use doesn't support appengine.

Comment: Is there any way to make the package app engine compatible? The package is for sending push notifications using onesignal

Comment: @farsanapb urlfetch should be passed Context via: `c := appengine.NewContext(r)`
 This `r` is request object. So adding context.Context for NewXXX seems to be good idea for me.

Answer (score 1):

A similar issue has been addressed by [Robby Colvin in this blog](https://robbycolvin.com/google-app-engine-http-default-transport/)

It explains how to make a third party package run in such conditions. Hoping this will help.